# Lubuntu 19.04 Opens PCManFM-Qt Without Proper Theme As Root

Tags: lubuntu, themes, 19.04, pcmanfm, lxqt

When opening PCManFM-Qt file manager as root from command line in Lubuntu 19.04, it opens using a default theme (which is rather ugly) and won't consider the choices made with lxqt-config. How do I change the root's lxqt theme so that PCManFM-Qt acknowledges it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it *is* considering your choice, but you don't have many applicable choices aside from Breeze/Windows/Fusion (none of which is a dark theme!). So you may want to install the package qt5-style-plugins, which enables the option "gtk2" in lxqt-config's Appearance section besides a few others. Selecting "gtk2" then makes the Qt theme engine imitate your GTK-2 theme.

```
sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins
```

Doing this prints the following:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  qt5-gtk2-platformtheme qt5-style-plugin-cleanlooks qt5-style-plugin-motif
  qt5-style-plugin-plastique qt5-style-plugins
```

Now go to lxqt-config's Appearance, and select "gtk2" as the Qt theme. This applies your selected GTK-2 theme (e.g. Arc-Dark) as the Qt engine's theme. Log out and log in again to make sure it is completely applied (I noticed a few buggy incomplete details when not logging out, fixed after doing so).

This [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183963/767323), specifically about the "gtk2" option, has a helpful screenshot.

### Explanation:

As PCMan (the main developer of PCManFM-Qt) says in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/issues/141#issuecomment-120404952), that file manager simply follows the default Qt theme engine, and there is no code to change that. This means that to change the styling of PCManFM-Qt, you must change the default theme of Qt applications.

Lubuntu currently ships with only three themes, Breeze/Windows/Fusion, and as somewhat helpfully hinted in the dialogue, the way to try to make Qt apps follow a GTK theme is by selecting "gtk2" as the Qt theme.