# Setting Pluma's Default File Manager

Tags: lubuntu, 19.04, pcmanfm, pluma

While messing around with Lubuntu 19.04, running lxqt-sudo to launch Pluma text editor as root so that I could edit the /var/www PHP projects I had, I noticed when rightclicking the file browser pane and choosing View Folder, that it opened up, at first, PCManFM-Qt. However, when it did so, it used a very ugly theme. (That's [another question I have posted](https://askubuntu.com/q/1139871/1698).) Then, I installed Nautilus. When I did, now when I open Pluma as root, it uses some file manager called Files, which I assume is Nautilus because it shows up when I do `ps -ef | grep -i nautilus`.

How do I tell Pluma to use PCManFM-Qt instead of Nautilus? What config file do I edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the default is done  with:

```
xdg-mime default pcmanfm-qt.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

(I assumed it is `pcmanfm-qt.desktop` so do check for the actual .desktop file inside `/usr/share/applications` folder.)

- `nautilus.desktop` for Nautilus.
- `nemo.desktop` for nemo.
- etc.

> when I open Pluma as root

Please stop this behaviour. Use `pkexec` instead.

But even then don't! If you need root to edit files in `/var/www/` your files are set incorrectly. Check the group of those files and add your user to that group. The group is going to be either `www-data` or `apache` if you use apache. Then you can edit the files from your user.

Comment: Note currently when I type `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`, it returns with `org.gnome,Nautilus.desktop` when in sudo su (root). But as a regular user, it returns with `pcmanfm-qt.desktop`. Perhaps this is useful info to someone.

Comment: As for `pkexec`, I'm glad you pointed out that tool to me. I had not seen it before. I really just need to edit the PHP files as the www-data user context. I haven't figured out how to make that work just yet -- it says `Cannot open display:`. Currently my launcher is using lxqt-sudo to launch Pluma as root, and being asked for my login  password on lxqt-sudo is annoying when it's just my local desktop.

Comment: see the addition ;-)

Comment: Thanks on that. Also, I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118825/22780) which explains how to get around the `Cannot open display` and `No protocol specified` problems.